# How to invoke my restful api method integrated with redis on windows?

Tags: java, spring, windows, redis, jedis

I am trying to run a sample spring boot application with redis.
I am using the jedis connection factory and setting it in Redis Template's connection factory.
I managed to find a MSI file to install redis on windows & I am able to see it running in the services window & also list the process of the same in the command prompt.
Getting 404 for the GET requests in the logs.

[image: redis command prompt process]

[image: redis instance running as a service]

[image: redis template/ jedis config code]

[image: code part 1]

[image: restful method which is not getting fired properly & ending up as 404]

[image: browser testing]

[image: intellij logs after invoking in browser]

Comment: What request? Can you should us how are you making the request? Is it postman or browser?

Comment: I m testing in browser.

Comment: please show me what you have typed in browser

Comment: updated body with the screenshots

Comment: it should be `localhost:8080/redis/finAll`

Comment: @SrikumarKrishnaIyer How about other endpoints? are they working like `/test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request should have been `localhost:8080/redis/findAll`, reason is that `@RequestMapping('redis')` at class level gets preprended before every request in that class